Anylogic Plot Chart using external data source
I want to create a chart in AnyLogic using external data (like an Excel sheet). The sheet contains time and value data. Could you provide the steps to create the chart based on this external data? I've already tried using the data in a collection, but it didn't work.

Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help

also, pls only use the "anylogic" tag, else other SOF users get confused :)
